# ASP.NET Code Expression, Data Binding, and other Declarative Expressoins

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

What are the differences in these tags?

<%
<%#
<%=
<%$

More importantly, how do I display a page property using declarative syntax in an ASP.NET control? I'm trying to do this in an ASP.NET control. The task is to set the text of a label but I do not want to do this pro grammatically in the event I want to change the output control. I get an error about server side controls can't contain this syntax. I'm not sure that I need a databound control for what I want to do but that is another option.

Partial answer coming up.

Update
There is a new tag I've seen in ASP.NET 4.5? site

<%:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Partial answer

quoted from Mike Banavige

> <% %>  An embedded code block is
>   server code that executes during the
>   page's render phase. The code in the
>   block can execute programming
>   statements and call functions in the
>   current page class.
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178135(vs.80).aspx
>
> <%= %> most useful for displaying
>   single pieces of information.
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5(VS.71).aspx
>
> <%# %> Data Binding Expression Syntax.
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx.aspx
>
> <%$ %> ASP.NET Expression.
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx
>
> <%@ %> Directive Syntax.
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz702w3e(VS.80).aspx
>
> <%-- --%> Server-Side Comments.
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4acf8afk.aspx

Update:

Okay this appears to work

```
<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# MyProperty%>'></asp:Label>
```

If I use the eval syntax then I get an error about databound control or I use the <% then I get a server side controls error. Any more color appreciated.. not sure I really understand what is going on.

Perhaps it has something to do with the render phase.

Few more observations:

I can use <%= without databinding and get the property value but can not use it in a server side control without getting error.

If I use <%# in server side control but I'm required to do a Page.Databind.

Interestingly, I can use either <%= or <%# when I want to render text that is not inside a control. Although the latter requires databinding.

The new <%: syntax is explained, also called code expression syntax

> With ASP.NET 4 we are introducing a new code expression syntax (<%: 
>   %>) that renders output like <%= %> blocks do – but which also
>   automatically HTML encodes it before doing so.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2

Comment: Another gotcha: The <%# %> tag must be the only value in the asp.net tag's attribute. e.g., you can't have ... Text="$<%# x.Amount %>" ...
It would have to be  ... Text="<%# "$" + x.Amount %>" ...

Answer (score 0):

No, server-side controls can't. For example, I have a string property named SkinPath that give me the full App_Themes path to the current theme. I use it in the following way:

```
<img src='<%= SkinPath %>/Images/myImage.png' />
```

However, the following doesn't work:

```
<asp:Image ID='image' runat='server' ImageUrl='<%= SkinPath %>/Images/myImage.png' />
```

Instead, it renders the `src` **literally** in the result `<img>`.

Comment: I updated my answer. I can use <%# and that works to databind to a property. Do you have more explanation why <% doesn't work? Is it because the way the render step works?

Comment: Curtis, I had a typo: I should have put <%= SkinPath %> and no, I don't have any reasoning for this. I do recall on one project before I got an error that was resolved by changing all the <%= to <%#. Some things you take the time to figure out. Other times, you get it done and get paid. :)