# What is difference between <%=%> and <%#%>

Tags: asp.net

All, As for the inline expression in asp.net ,I had some questions about them.

1. What is the difference between them ?
2. In what situation ,Which one is better?

By the way, I found below code the first one doesn't works , but second one works. Why?

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="<%#FullyQualifiedApplicationPath%>Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head><!--Not OK-->

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="<%=FullyQualifiedApplicationPath%>Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head><!--OK-->
```

`FullyQualifiedApplicationPath` is a variable defined in code behind. Thanks your review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<%= %> is for loading variables
<%# %> is for databaind

Consult [this post](http://forums.asp.net/post/1828702.aspx) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727877/asp-net-databinding-server-tags-differences-declarative-output-property) for more info

Answer (score 2):

[`<%=%>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5%28VS.71%29.aspx) is the equivalent of Response.Write or for writing directly to the page (response), while [`<%# %>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is used specifically for databinding.

Answer (score 2):

<%#%> is used to bind some data or control by using BIND(read and write purpose) or EVAL(for readonly purpose).

Where as <%=%> is used to display the value of a session in a html page.

Answer (score 1):

For example when u w3ant to bind data to a grid we use the following syntax

```
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lbl_Id" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
```

The above syntax is used to bind the data in the gridview

while the <%=%> You will be able to do c# coding in default. aspx page as well, here is the sample code.

```
To show some output on the page and do some coding over out there


  <%=Session["value"].ToString() %>
```

It will load the session value in the default page.